# Python PANDAS: Stack and Enumerate Date to Create New Records

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe with the following general format:

```
id,transaction_dt,units,measure
1,2014-01-06,30,30.5
1,2014-02-04,5,22.6
```

What I hoping to accomplish is the following:

Create new records based on adding the units to transaction_dt as days by id to create a result dataframe that looks like this:

```
id,enumerated_dt,measure
1,2014-01-06,30.5
1,2014-01-07,30.5
1,2014-01-08,30.5
...
1,2014-02-05,30.5
1,2014-02-04,22.6
1,2014-02-05,22.6
...
```

I think stack might be part of the solution, but I am currently stumped on how to enumerate/increment the date in a performant way.  Any advice or solutions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: on second glance, it looks like you do want to fill the gaps in your dates, and then forward-fill your data, which can be done as easily as:

```
df.set_index('transaction_dt').resample('D').ffill()
```

If, however you don't want to create a continuous index, but rather to add an arbitrary number of rows `N`, you could do this by first moving 'transaction_dt' to your index:

```
df.set_index('transaction_dt', inplace=True)
```

...and then using this lambda function (making use of numpy methods):

```
add_n_dates = lambda n: df.index.repeat(n) + \
                        np.tile(np.arange(n)*pd.Timedelta('1 days'), df.index.size)
```

... to add `n` dates to each element of your new index, before finally reindexing + forward-filling:

```
df.reindex(add_n_dates(5), method='ffill')

#                  id  units  measure
# transaction_dt                     
# 2014-01-06      1.0   30.0     30.5
# 2014-01-07      1.0   30.0     30.5
# 2014-01-08      1.0   30.0     30.5
# 2014-01-09      1.0   30.0     30.5
# 2014-01-10      1.0   30.0     30.5
# 2014-02-04      1.0    5.0     22.6
# 2014-02-05      1.0    5.0     22.6
# 2014-02-06      1.0    5.0     22.6
# 2014-02-07      1.0    5.0     22.6
# 2014-02-08      1.0    5.0     22.6
```

Edit #2:

Assuming again that you've already set your index to `transaction_dt`, this may be the easiest approach to using the values in `units` to determine how many rows to add. It uses `pd.date_range` to create the necessary date values by passing `row.name` (i.e. its index value) as the starting point and `row.units` as the # of periods to generate.

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.name, periods=x.units)), axis=1). \
    stack(). \
    reset_index(level=1). \
    join(df['measure']). \
    drop('level_1', axis=1). \
    reset_index(). \
    rename(columns={0:'enumerated_dt'})

#    transaction_dt enumerated_dt  measure
# 0      2014-01-06    2014-01-06     30.5
# 1      2014-01-06    2014-01-07     30.5
# 2      2014-01-06    2014-01-08     30.5
# 3      2014-01-06    2014-01-09     30.5
# 4      2014-01-06    2014-01-10     30.5
# ...
# 29     2014-01-06    2014-02-04     30.5
# 30     2014-02-04    2014-02-04     22.6
# 31     2014-02-04    2014-02-05     22.6
# 32     2014-02-04    2014-02-06     22.6
# 33     2014-02-04    2014-02-07     22.6
# 34     2014-02-04    2014-02-08     22.6
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is very helpful.  The thing I am trying to ascertain now is how to apply your numpy function using the units field to determine the n dates added?

Comment: @Pylander please see the new option presented in my revised answer. In order to determine the number of dates/rows to add with values from `units`, we can rely solely on pandas functionality.

Comment: your edit #2 accomplishes exactly what I need!  i'm going to work of testing/optimizing it on my end.  any parting thoughts on things I might want to look at for future ways to even further improve performance?

Comment: Glad to hear it! There are likely other ways of achieving this output with pandas, but I'm not sure what performance gains there would be -- any pandas solution that I can think of will require an `apply` somewhere, and subsequent reshaping. You may find speed gains with a strictly numpy approach (e.g. generating an array of all of the dates you need, and then reindexing with the array and ffilling.), but I imagine you'd need to split the work into multiple commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a help dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'transaction_dt':pd.date_range('2014-01-06',periods = 35,freq='D')})

df.merge(df1,how='left').ffill()
Out[879]: 
   transaction_dt   id  units  measure
0      2014-01-06  1.0   30.0     30.5
1      2014-01-07  1.0   30.0     30.5
2      2014-01-08  1.0   30.0     30.5
3      2014-01-09  1.0   30.0     30.5
4      2014-01-10  1.0   30.0     30.5
5      2014-01-11  1.0   30.0     30.5
6      2014-01-12  1.0   30.0     30.5
7      2014-01-13  1.0   30.0     30.5
8      2014-01-14  1.0   30.0     30.5
9      2014-01-15  1.0   30.0     30.5
10     2014-01-16  1.0   30.0     30.5
11     2014-01-17  1.0   30.0     30.5
12     2014-01-18  1.0   30.0     30.5
13     2014-01-19  1.0   30.0     30.5
14     2014-01-20  1.0   30.0     30.5
15     2014-01-21  1.0   30.0     30.5
16     2014-01-22  1.0   30.0     30.5
17     2014-01-23  1.0   30.0     30.5
18     2014-01-24  1.0   30.0     30.5
19     2014-01-25  1.0   30.0     30.5
20     2014-01-26  1.0   30.0     30.5
21     2014-01-27  1.0   30.0     30.5
22     2014-01-28  1.0   30.0     30.5
23     2014-01-29  1.0   30.0     30.5
24     2014-01-30  1.0   30.0     30.5
25     2014-01-31  1.0   30.0     30.5
26     2014-02-01  1.0   30.0     30.5
27     2014-02-02  1.0   30.0     30.5
28     2014-02-03  1.0   30.0     30.5
29     2014-02-04  1.0    5.0     22.6
30     2014-02-05  1.0    5.0     22.6
31     2014-02-06  1.0    5.0     22.6
32     2014-02-07  1.0    5.0     22.6
33     2014-02-08  1.0    5.0     22.6
34     2014-02-09  1.0    5.0     22.6
```